# Physical dimensions(size) of the new MKR1000 board?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano

Anybody here knows the physical dimensions(size) of the new Aduino MKR1000 board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the diagram on [the main page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMKR1000) is to scale, then it's approximately 2.2 inches by 1.0 inches.

Comment: Exactly! I had the same figures in mind.